# Arabic Characters in SQL Server has strange form

Tags: sql-server

I have a Database backup of extension .bak
I tried to retrieve some data from it, it contains Arabic letters. But the Arabic letters was in the form of --> Ã.ÅÓãÇÚíá ÍÇÝÙ ÇáãÕãã

So, is there any way to retrieve the data in its original form?

Comment: No you cannot. It has been inserted badly in the first place. Either use an Arabic collation, or use Unicode literals prefixed with `N`

Comment: Please clarify exactly how you're retrieving the data.  It's possible that the data was corrupted before being stored by conversion to a code page that doesn't have Arabic characters, but it's also possible it's stored correctly but you're messing it up when reading it.  And you can see the raw data by casting it to varbinary, eg `select cast(somecolumn as varbinary(8000)) from sometable`.

Comment: could you say what is data type of the column?